# ERROR 1111 (HY000): Invalid use of group function MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I want show the result

```
SELECT GolDarah, count(GolDarah) JmlPasien
FROM tblPasien
WHERE monthname(TglLahir) IN ('July','August','September','October','November','December') AND count(GolDarah) JmlPasien = 2
GROUP BY GolDarah
ORDER BY GolDarah;
```

I Want show the result, but error.
ERROR 1111 (HY000): Invalid use of group function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should to use `HAVING` statement like:

```
    SELECT GolDarah, count(GolDarah) JmlPasien
    FROM tblPasien
    WHERE monthname(TglLahir) IN ('July','August','September','October','November','December') 
    GROUP BY GolDarah
    HAVING count(GolDarah) = 2
    ORDER BY GolDarah;
```

also WHERE statement can be more effective like:

```
 WHERE month(TglLahir) > 5
```

Comment: Empty set, 10 warnings (0.001 sec)

Comment: SELECT GolDarah, count(GolDarah) JmlPasien
    -> FROM tblPasien
    -> WHERE monthname(TglLahir) > 5
    -> GROUP BY GolDarah
    -> HAVING count(GolDarah) = 2
    -> ORDER BY GolDarah;
Empty set, 10 warnings (0.001 sec)